# how to install node-sass-middleware

Tags: mongodb, express

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\HTML coding ninza\basic\resume\Node js\major project social media\cod\node_modules\node-sass-middleware\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\HTML coding ninza\basic\resume\Node js\major project social media\cod\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\HTML coding ninza\basic\resume\Node js\major project social media\cod\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',

node-sass-middleware need to install successfully

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.